# Compare elements of 2d Array to each-other and store this in a map with tuple

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, hashmap

I have this `2d-Array`

`[[1, path1, path2, path3, path5],
 [0, path1, path3, path5], 
[1, path1, path2, path5]]`

I want to store its element in a `Map` like this `Map<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> information;`

The first Integer is the counter path with `1` and the sec integer is the counter path with `0`

the expected output is therefore like this.

`path1->(2,1) // because the path1 is 2 times appeared with in the 2d-Array with 1 and 1 times with 0.
 path2->(2,0)
 path3->(1,1) 
 path5->(2,1)`

This is my try, i stoped because it did not know how to comparing the elements and store its element in the `Map`.
import java.util.*;

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List < List < String >> all = new ArrayList < > ();
        List < String > arr1 = new ArrayList < > ();
        arr1.add("1");
        arr1.add("path1");
        arr1.add("path2");
        arr1.add("path3");
        arr1.add("path5");
        ////////

        List < String > arr2 = new ArrayList < > ();
        arr2.add("0");
        arr2.add("path1");
        arr2.add("path3");
        arr2.add("path5");
        ////////

        List < String > arr3 = new ArrayList < > ();
        arr3.add("1");
        arr3.add("path1");
        arr3.add("path2");
        arr3.add("path5");
        ////////
        all.add(arr1);
        all.add(arr2);
        all.add(arr3);

        Map < String, Pair < Integer, Integer >> information;

        System.out.println(all);

        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < all.get(i).size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(all.get(i).get(j));

            }

        }

    }





    public class Pair < L, R > {

        private final L left;
        private final R right;

        public Pair(L left, R right) {
            assert left != null;
            assert right != null;

            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public L getLeft() {
            return left;
        }
        public R getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return left.hashCode() ^ right.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
            Pair pairo = (Pair) o;
            return this.left.equals(pairo.getLeft()) &&
                this.right.equals(pairo.getRight());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since arithmetic operations are not allowed on generics, we should cast that generic value to an integer (only if you are sure that value is an integer) or else instead of generics you can use primitive data types. Since you coded using generics, I used generics for implementation. Otherwise, I would recommend using primitive data types for your requirement. The following code would do what you asked:

```
    public class HelloWorld {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            String[] inputArray[] = {{"1", "path1", "path2", "path3", "path5"}, {"0", "path1", "path3", "path5"}, {"1", "path1", "path2", "path5"}};
            HashMap<String, Tuple> map = new HashMap<String, Tuple>();
            for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                String[] individualArray = inputArray[i];

                for (int j = 0; j < individualArray.length; j++) {
                    //int[] tuple = new int[2];
                    Tuple tuple;
                    if(map.containsKey(individualArray[j]))
                    {
                        tuple = map.get(individualArray[j]);

                        if(individualArray[0].equals("1"))
                        {
                            int counter = (int)tuple.getLeft();
                            counter = counter+1;
                            tuple.setLeft(counter);
                            //tuple[0]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int counter = (int)tuple.getRight();
                            counter = counter+1;
                            tuple.setRight(counter);
                            //tuple[1]++;
                        }
                        map.put(individualArray[j], tuple);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(individualArray[0].equals("1"))
                        {
                            tuple = new Tuple(1,0);
                        /*
                         * tuple[0] = 1; tuple[1] = 0;
                         */
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tuple = new Tuple(0,1);
                        /*
                         * tuple[0] = 0; tuple[1] = 1;
                         */
                        }


                        map.put(individualArray[j], tuple);
                    }

                }




                }

                //System.out.println( map.get("path5").getLeft() +" , "+ map.get("path5").getRight());



        }
```

```
public class Tuple<L,R> {

    private L left;
    private R right;

    public Tuple() {
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public L getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(L left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public R getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(R right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Tuple(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }



}
```

Comment: Could you please imporve your solution with `Tuple` data structure instead of `int[]` i would be very thankful

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to prevent using setter method? and get the same result?

Comment: Try to get the variables instead of calling setter method

Comment: The problem is that the class pair should be immutible. Any solution for that please

Comment: I have a question please how can i add a counter which has the number of arrays that has number `1` and the arrays has number `0` into the class tuple as additional attribute ? please help me